# Relations between sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a[n]}{n!}=\frac{a[1]}{1}+ \frac{a[2]}{2}+ \frac{a[3]}{6}+ \frac{a[4]}{24}+\dots=I$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a[n]}{(n-1)!}=\frac{a[1]}{1}+ \frac{a[2]}{1}+ \frac{a[3]}{2}+ \frac{a[4]}{6}+\dots=J$$

Is there a way to express $J$ only in terms of $I$?

$a[n]$ are polynomials in terms of X that satisfy the following relation: 
$$
\frac{d}{d X} a[n] = n (n-1) a[n-1] - n \frac{d}{d X}  a[n-1]  
$$

Comment: Not in general, though perhaps in some special cases of $a[n]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach if $a_n$ ever becomes known in some sense would be through exponential generating functions. Define
$$
f_I(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n
$$
and note that
$$
\begin{split}
f_i'(x)
 &= \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n \right]
  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n \right] \\
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} 
  = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!} x^n \\
 &= \frac{f_J(x)}{x}
\end{split}
$$
and knowing the relationship between generating functions $f_J(x) = xf_I'(x)$ will help compute the underlying sequences as well.

That said, analytically computing one sequence in terms of the other is not possible without further information on $a_n$...

Comment: $a[n]$ are polynomials in terms of X that satisfy the following relation: $ \frac{d}{d X} a[n] = n (n-1) a[n-1] - n \frac{d}{d X}  a[n-1]  $